# failed to connect postgres database running on heroku

Tags: c#, postgresql, heroku

i want to view data table on my postgres database running on heroku.i can view my table throw view.php which was included to same server.but when i try to connect pg database throw c# ,it gives me error.i recognize that host is in error is my ip address .
after googling i found that i need to edit hba.pba file.i have installed psql(shell) terminal and i try command SHOW hba_file .but it's say must be superuser to examine "hba_file" can someone help me to solve my problem

```
Npgsql.NpgsqlException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467259
  Message=FATAL: 28000: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "61.642.163.26", user "fharmfggzvbzn", database "df4a8lse4537sb", SSL off
  Source=Npgsql
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  BaseMessage=no pg_hba.conf entry for host "61.642.163.26", user "fharmfggzvbzn", database "df4a8lse4537sb", SSL off
  Code=28000
  ColumnName=""
  ConstraintName=""
  DataTypeName=""
  Detail=""
  ErrorSql=""
  File=auth.c
  Hint=""
  Line=486
  Position=""
  Routine=ClientAuthentication
  SchemaName=""
  Severity=FATAL
  TableName=""
  Where=""
  StackTrace:
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlState.<ProcessBackendResponses_Ver_3>d__9.MoveNext()
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlState.ProcessAndDiscardBackendResponses(NpgsqlConnector context)
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectedState.Startup(NpgsqlConnector context, NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open()
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectorPool.GetPooledConnector(NpgsqlConnection Connection)
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectorPool.RequestPooledConnectorInternal(NpgsqlConnection Connection)
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectorPool.RequestConnector(NpgsqlConnection Connection)
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()
       at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Madhawa\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs:line 57
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at WindowsFormsApplication1.Program.Main() in c:\Users\Madhawa\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\Program.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

after googling i found that i need to edit hba.pba file.i have installed psql(shell) terminal and i try command  SHOW hba_file .but it's say must be superuser to examine "hba_file" can someone help me to solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crucial point there is:

> `Message=FATAL: 28000: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "61.642.163.26", user "fharmfggzvbzn", database "df4a8lse4537sb"`, **SSL off**

You must request an SSL connection. Heroku does not permit non-SSL connections. See [the nPgSQL documentation for how to request an SSL connection](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.ConnectionString.html).

You cannot edit `pg_hba.conf` on Heroku, it's a managed PostgreSQL install that you don't get full control of (but in exchange, you don't have to manage it as much).